# Print object as JSON in NLog with multiple arguments

Tags: .net, arguments, nlog

I am getting started using NLog, with just a simple file output:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target
            name="logFile"
            xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log.txt"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/Log.{#}.txt"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            maxArchiveFiles="60"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="iso-8859-2" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I discovered that I was able to [serialise objects in JSON form](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#formatting-of-the-message) for logging, using the `@` prefix, eg:

```
Logger.Debug("Request: {@0}", request);
```

And that work fine, as long as I only have a single argument.  But then I started to discover unformatted placeholders in my logs:

```
Processing purchase order {0}/{1} for user {@2}
```

After some investigation it seems to be related to whether I'm using named or numbered indexes, and the position of the JSON-format prefix `@`.  I wrote up a quick test:

```
User user = new User("Bill", "Gates", "12345");

Logger.Info("All numbered");
Logger.Info("0: {@0}, 1: {1}", user, 1);       // 0: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"}, 1: 1 
Logger.Info("0: {0}, 1: {@1}", 1, user);       // 0: {0}, 1: {@1} 

Logger.Info("Object named, int numbered");
Logger.Info("User: {@user}, 1: {1}", user, 1); // User: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"}, 1: 1 
Logger.Info("0: {0}, User: {@user}", user, 1); // 0: {0}, User: {@user} 

Logger.Info("Object numbered, int named");
Logger.Info("0: {@0}, n: {n}", user, 1);       // 0: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"}, n: 1 
Logger.Info("n: {n}, 1: {@1}", 1, user);       // n: 1, 1: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"} 

Logger.Info("All named");
Logger.Info("User: {@user}, n: {n}", user, 1); // User: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"}, n: 1 
Logger.Info("n: {n}, User: {@user}", 1, user); // n: 1, User: {"FirstName":"Bill", "LastName":"Gates", "Id":"12345"}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Surely the rule isn't "If using `@` it must be the first argument, or it must follow a named argument".  I realise the details about the `@` prefix are under the structured logging section, but I don't fully understand it.  Am I not allowed to use this with a flat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog "cheats" and only activates its message-template-parser, when it sees the first
place-holder uses message-template-logic (Like using a name or `@`).

NLog fallback to standard `string.Format` when it doesn't need to use message-template-parser. This is both for performance, but also to reduce the chance of breaking changes from not using `string.Format` when expected.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#combine-indexed-and-structured-logging

Comment: Wow, my sarcastic guess "If using @ it must be the first argument, or it must follow a named argument" was pretty much spot on.  Ok, thanks for the link.  I didn't fully understand it treated positional so differently from named (structured).